# If $X$ and $Y$ are both linear combinations of the same random variables, will they have to be dependent?

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose I have random variables $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, both with normal distribution. If I set $X=c_1 Z_1+c_2Z_2$ and $Y=c_3Z_1 +c_4Z_2$, will they have to be dependent?

What is the way to interpret the relationship between $X$ and $Y$? How would you find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: What is some cs are zero?

Comment: If $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are joint normal then it is easy to find the joint density: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation.
If you do not know their dependence you cannot find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ since you don't even know the joint pdf of $(Z_1, Z_2)$

Answer (score 1):

For the $cov(X,Y)$ you would have
$$
cov(c_1Z_1+c_2Z_2, c_3 Z_1+c_4Z_2) = c_1^2c_3^2cov(Z_1,Z_1) + (c_1^2c_4^2+c_2^2c_3^2)cov(Z_1,Z_2)+c_2^2c_4^2cov(Z_2,Z_2) = c_1^2c_3^2\sigma_{Z_1}^2 + (c_1^2c_4^2+c_2^2c_3^2)\sigma_{Z_1}\sigma_{Z_2}corr(Z_1,Z_2)+c_2^2c_4^2\sigma_{Z_2}^2.
$$

Comment: What is their joint density?